# Sorting citations in \nocite

Tags: biblatex

I have this problem that I simply cannot figure out despite having deep trawled the net.
I would like to have two bibliographies. One that keeps citations that I cite in the text, and one for all citations (e.g. a complete publication list). The former should be ordered in the order I cite them, while the latter should be ordered by year.

The problem for the latter is that I can make it ordered by year using the `\nocite{*}`, but they will be numbered in the (arbitrary) ordering they where written in bibtex. A min working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{ref2014,
  author = {First, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Funny title 1},
  pages = {1--3}}
@article{ref2012,
  author = {Second, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Funny title 2},
  pages = {1--3}}
@article{ref2013,
  author = {Third, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Funny title 3},
  pages = {1--3}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Interesting text}
\begin{refsection}[mybib]
Citing some stuff \cite{ref2013,ref2012} numbered in the order I cite     them\cite{ref2014}.
\printbibliography[title=Citations]   
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[mybib]
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography[sorting=ynt,title={Entire publication list sorted by year}]   
\end{refsection}
  \end{document}
```

Now my *Entire publication list sorted by year* is sorted by year but numbered in the order `2,3,1`. I want it to be `1,2,3`.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `biblatex`-commands `\ateverycite` and `\addtocategory` to differ between cited and noncited bibentries.

For the different sortings you set the biblatex-option `defernumbers=true`, and use `resetnumbers=true` as option in the `\printbibliography`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,
sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}%mod.

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{ref2014,
  author = {First, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2014},
  title = {Funny title 1},
  pages = {1--3}}
@article{ref2012,
  author = {Second, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2012},
  title = {Funny title 2},
  pages = {1--3}}
@article{ref2013,
  author = {Third, Author},
  volume = {54},
  number = {2},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. {\O}},
  year = {2013},
  title = {Funny title 3},
  pages = {1--3}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Interesting text}
\begin{refsection}[mybib]
Citing some stuff \cite{ref2013,ref2012} numbered in the order I cite them.
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,title=Citations,category=cited]%mod
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[mybib]
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true,sorting=ynt,%mod
title={Entire publication list sorted by year}]   
\end{refsection}
  \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]